# Event listener doesn't work for Enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

What may be the reason, that event listener of `Enter` key doesn't work?

I tried both plain JS:

```
addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        enter(e);
    }
});

function enter(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You pressed enter");
}
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Also, I tried both `event` and `e`. Doesn't work. For another key, for example `Backspace` it works well.

That is a plugin for our corporate intranet - when you click some letter in email inbox, and after that press `Enter`, small pop-up window must be shown. But for some reason `Enter` is ignored in my script - instead of showing pop-up, webpage immediately opens the letter (that is a default behavior).

As I understand, the reason may be in another listener somewhere in webmail interface? Or not? If yes, may I somehow impart higher priority for handling `Enter` (so, before opening the letter, pop-up will be shown)?

Apologize for long description.

Comment: addEventListener... is there more to that first line?

Comment: Curently I use just that

Comment: Well, that would be a problem... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

It should work as long as you bind the event handler within the `document.ready`

```
$(function(){

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {

       if(event.which == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          alert('You pressed enter!');
       }
   });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/kimoho/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: It should work. See the link i posted in the answer. I guess you have some other errors in your other part of js. Check your browser console.